# Does adding 1066Mhz DDR3 SODIMM to a 1600Mhz FSB laptop make sense?

Tags: memory, clockspeed

My *previous* laptop had 4x4GB **1066** Mhz DDR3.

My *new* laptop instead has only 2x4GB **1600** Mhz DDR3.

Using dmidecode I gather my FSB is set to 2300Mhz.

> Max Speed: 3800 MHz
>   Current Speed: 2300 MHz

2 questions:

- Can somebody confirm I can safely add two "old" 1066Mhz modules to my
  *new* laptop before I treat myself to faster DDR3 modules?
- I understand this should not slow down the faster 2 1600 Mhz DDR3 modules. Correct?

If this is of any relevance, I'm running Linux Mint Maya.

Comment: If you put slower memory in your computer then ALL memory will be ran at that speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will slow it down.

- All RAM modules work at the same speed.
- The best way this is done by the system is make them all work at the slowest speed.
- You can definitely add your older RAM modules safely to you new laptop.
- However, if you add 2 x 4GB modules @ 1066Mhz, the 2 x 4GB modules @ 1600Mhz will also work @ 1066Mhz
- Ideally, all your RAM modules should be identical for best performance.

Comment: Just to clarify, it'll slow down the RAM modules, not the computer itself (at least not perceivably).